# Unable to connect to Bluetooth Mate Silver

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I am trying to connect my laptop running ubuntu 12.04 to a Bluetooth Mate Silver connected to an arduino.

Wiring is :

- CTS-I->No connection (leave floating)
- VCC->5V
- GND->GND
- TX-O->D2
- RX-I->D3
- RTS-O->No connection (leave floating)

Code running on arduino :

```
    $include <SoftwareSerial.h>  

    int bluetoothTx = 2;  // TX-O pin of bluetooth mate, Arduino D2
    int bluetoothRx = 3;  // RX-I pin of bluetooth mate, Arduino D3

    SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);

    void setup()
    {
      Serial.begin(9600);  // Begin the serial monitor at 9600bps

      bluetooth.begin(115200);  // The Bluetooth Mate defaults to 115200bps
      bluetooth.print("$$$");  // Enter command mode
      delay(100);  // Short delay, wait for the Mate to send back CMD
      bluetooth.println("U,9600,N");  // Temporarily Change the baudrate to 9600, no parity
      // 115200 can be too fast at times for NewSoftSerial to relay the data reliably
      bluetooth.begin(9600);  // Start bluetooth serial at 9600
    }

    void loop()
    {
      if(bluetooth.available())  // If the bluetooth sent any characters
      {
        // Send any characters the bluetooth prints to the serial monitor
        Serial.print((char)bluetooth.read());  
      }
      if(Serial.available())  // If stuff was typed in the serial monitor
      {
        // Send any characters the Serial monitor prints to the bluetooth
        bluetooth.print((char)Serial.read());
      }
      // and loop forever and ever!
    }
```

When I open the bluetooth manager in ubuntu I find that the bluetooth mate is visible but unknown and there is no SPP connection option when I right click on it. All the tutorials and blogs I went through connected to bluetooth mate through the SPP option.

Pic of my bluetooth manager : 
http://www2.picturepush.com/photo/a/12001550/640/12001550.jpg

So now how do I connect to the bluetooth mate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of googling and reading various blogs I came across this command :

```
    sudo rfcomm bind 0 00:06:66:48:71:0C
```

where 00:06:66:48:71:0C is the mac address of the bluetooth mate silver.

Once I did that I found that the serial port option for my device in the bluetooth manager was enabled. 
I continue from there to connect to the device.